# shaka configure to choose the Representation and Adaptationset you want to play

Tags: shaka

I am trying to configure shaka-player to play the UHD representation from my manifest instead of the SD. My question is:

1. How does it decide which Representation to play?
2. How can you define which representation to play?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally used Dashjs instead of shaka-player which starts with highest bitrate instead of lowest one.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using shaka UI, the UI will include playback selection.
https://shaka-player-demo.appspot.com/docs/api/shaka.ui.PlaybackRateSelection.html
https://shaka-player-demo.appspot.com/docs/api/tutorial-ui.html

https://shaka-player-demo.appspot.com/docs/api/shaka.Player.html
selectVariantsByLabel(label)
selectVariantTrack(track, clearBufferopt, safeMarginopt)